# How to enable or disable a value inside a combobox if a specific time range is not met

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello I have a program that has a series of comboboxes that users can pick different values from. One of the cb has a 1, 2, and 3 int value in it. The values correspond to first, second and third shift, respectively. I would like to disable values 2 and 3 if the system time is from 6 am. Till 2 pm. And then do the same thing for the other shifts. Disable or grey out the number 1 and 3 if the system time is from 2 pm till 10 pm. And disable CB values 1 and 2 if the system time is anywhere from 10 pm. to 6 am. I am currently showing the system time inside a label on the UI using a timer.
I don't know where to begin. I've looked in Google and all the answers there, pertain to WPF or Javascript not Winforms. Is this function even possible in WinForms c#?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't disable items in a combobox. You have to remove/add them, but that's easy enough to do.

Comment: @itsme86: With owner-drawn combo boxes you can do anything you please.  There isn't much difference between a non-selectable heading/grouping and a non-selectable disabled item.  Definitely a lot of work involved in getting it behaving as expected, though.

Comment: @OP: It sounds as if the shift is completely determined by the current time (there's only one "enabled" option).  In that case, why give the user a combobox at all, just show them what shift it is (you can use a disabled combobox or textbox, or a simple label, to display such information).

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This answer borrowed heavily from [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/3222/how-to-disable-some-items-of-a-combobox.aspx), written by [Apurba Ranjan](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/members/apurba-ranjan).

---

One "hacky" thing you can do is create a custom class for your combo box items that contains an `Enabled` property:

```
class ComboBoxItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }

    public ComboBoxItem(string text, bool enabled)
    {
        Text = text;
        Enabled = enabled;
    }
}
```

Then, when we add items of this class to the combo box, we set the `Enabled` property based on the current time (note that we also set the `DisplayMember` and hook up an event handler for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cboShifts.DisplayMember = "Text";
    cboShifts.SelectedIndexChanged += CboShifts_SelectedIndexChanged;

    var currentTime = DateTime.Now;

    var firstEnabled = currentTime >= DateTime.Parse("6:00 AM") && 
                       currentTime < DateTime.Parse("2:00 PM");

    var secondEnabled = currentTime >= DateTime.Parse("2:00 PM") && 
                        currentTime < DateTime.Parse("10:00 PM");

    var thirdEnabled = !firstEnabled && !secondEnabled;

    cboShifts.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("1", firstEnabled));
    cboShifts.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("2", secondEnabled));
    cboShifts.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem("3", thirdEnabled));
}
```

Then, in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event, we can get the selected item and if it's `null` (meaning selected index is `-1`) then we return, otherwise if its `Enabled` property is `false`, we set the selected index to `-1` (basically not allowing them to select it):

```
private void CboShifts_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (sender as ComboBox)?.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (item == null) return;

    // Don't let the user select a disabled item
    if (!item.Enabled)
    {
        cboShifts.SelectedIndex = -1;
        MessageBox.Show($"Item '{item.Text}' is not enabled");
        return;
    }

    // Optionally do something here for a valid selection
}
```